# Possible to add any checks beyond type in BigQuery table?

Tags: google-bigquery

Other than specifying the type of a column, are there any additional constraints that can be added? For example:

```
CREATE TABLE team(
  code VARCHAR, 
  conference VARCHAR,
  UNIQUE INDEX (code, conference), 
  CHECK (code is not null)
);
```

In other words, anything like:

- Unique
- Check
- Constraint/references

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery doesn't enforce referential integrity constraints like uniqueness.

You can however control column nullability (e.g. making a value required, disallowing NULLs).

Additionally, some types support [parameterization](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#parameterized_data_types), e.g. restricting the max length of strings/byte values, or constraining the precision/scale of decimal types.

Answer (score 0):

Biquery is a columnar database, and did not have unique indexes, if you need unique identifier to identfy each row, need to add in your code logic to insert in BQ.
For better understanding you can refer this bq documents
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables-intro